# Azure storage blobs, Download file and check integrity

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have code which does this today running in production to do data integrity checks by relying on blob.properties.ContentMD5 hash.

Our organization recommended to move out of MD5 in production code due to compliance and we are looking for ways to change our code.

azure blob doesnt have any other properties to do data integrity checks so instead of MD5 how can we do that ? any suggestions

blob.Propertis.ContentMD5.

Sample code:

```
string hashFromXstore = blob.Propertis.ContentMD; 
string localHash = HashGenerator.ComputeMD5(<path to destination>);

if(hashFromXstore  ! = localHash)
     throw exception ("downloaded file does not have right MD5 hash");
```

researching into CRC64 check sum and looking for suggestions.